# Layout behavior when routing (Vue.js2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm planning to have the following layout:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                  HEADER (STATIC)                |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|         FOREWORD (just homepage; dynamic)       |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                  BOOTSTRAP CARDS                |
|              with navigation links              |
|                    (dynamic)                    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Since it's a Single Page App, I'm using Vue.js with routing to make sure everything gets displayed in the same view. However, trying various modifications to make the `dynamic` contents disappear and be replaced with a different page selected from the Bootstrap cards doesn't give results I'd like to achieve (links from cards and cards themselves don't disappear and the contents of destination links gets displayed in a spot where `<router-view></router-view>` is placed. I'd like the FOREWORD and BOOTSTRAP CARDS to be totally replaced by destination links).

Is there any dedicated way to achieve this? Or should I just manipulate with `v-if` and a show/hide flag defined in JS underneath to hide the `dynamic` contents when links from cards get selected?

Comment: Setup "named views" - look in the official docs, or make the `router-view` component contain the foreword and the cards.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Made some twists and finally got what I wanted! Please publish it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup "named views" - look in the official docs, or make the router-view component contain the foreword and the cards.

Glad you got it figured out.